# Django Form Submit 'null value in column "project_id" violates not-null constraint', but Form is valid

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a form that is two values, a name and a foreign key reference to a parent id.
When I submit the form, it validates and I can see the two values (name and parent id), but upon saving I get a null constraint error.

Model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    """Product object containing LCI information for contained substances."""
    name = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=255)
    stages = models.ManyToManyField('LifeCycleStage')
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Form:

```
class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    """
    Base form for creating a new product.
    """
    # Product Name
    name = CharField(
        max_length=255,
        widget=TextInput({'class': 'form-control mb-2', 'placeholder': 'Product Name'}),
        label=_("Product Name"), required=True)
    project_id = IntegerField(
        widget=NumberInput({'class': 'form-control mb-2', 'readonly': 'readonly'}),
        required=True, label=_("Parent Project"))

    class Meta:
        """Meta data for Product form."""

        model = Product
        fields = ('name', 'project_id')
```

Post method:

```
@method_decorator(login_required)
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """Process the post request with a new Product form filled out."""
    form = ProductForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        product_obj = form.save(commit=True)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/products/create/lifecyclestage?product_id=' + product_obj.id)
    return render(request, "create.html", {'form': form})
```

Completed and validated form in the view:
[Completed and validated form in the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kDOR.png)

Template error:

```
IntegrityError at /products/create/
null value in column "project_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (4, Test Product, null).
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:58661/products/create/
Django Version: 2.2.5
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
null value in column "project_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (4, Test Product, null).
Exception Location: C:\Users\JacobS\Envs\proj\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py in _execute, line 84
Python Executable:  C:\Users\JacobS\Envs\proj\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.4
```

Please let me know if there's any more information I can provide.
I have no idea why the object is failing to save to the database, if anyone can help me out it'd be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The model field is called `project`, not `project_id`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Can you clarify? I realize that the model has a project reference, but in the database that's denoted with an integer ID reference. It seems to me that referencing the ID in the form would be valid. Are you saying that the form should have a Project object reference itself, as opposed to the project ID foreign key reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form goes by the names in the model, not the database. So `project_id` isn't recognised as anything other than a standalone IntegerField, and isn't related to the model field `project`.

But you don't really need any of this. Django is already expecting to receive an ID for a ForeignKey field, which it will internally translate to the relevant instance of the related model. So assuming your aim is to allow the user to enter an ID directly, all you need to do is to change the widget of the project field:

```
class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    name = CharField(
        max_length=255,
        widget=TextInput({'class': 'form-control mb-2', 'placeholder': 'Product Name'}),
        label=_("Product Name"), required=True)
    project = ModelChoiceField(
        model=Project,
        widget=NumberInput({'class': 'form-control mb-2', 'readonly': 'readonly'}),
        required=True, label=_("Parent Project"))

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('name', 'project')
```

or, more concisely:

```
class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('name', 'project')
        labels = {'name': 'Product Name', 'project': 'Parent Project'}
        widgets = {
            'name': TextInput({'class': 'form-control mb-2', 'placeholder': 'Product Name'})
            'project': NumberInput({'class': 'form-control mb-2', 'readonly': 'readonly'})
        }
```